# hyperlink doesnt affect all the area of the post

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a wordpress posts link and around list item (each post) i have hyperlink, but the problem is that mu hyperlink becomes with width and height of 0 and all that block of post is not linkable, however in the source code from browser i can see that it shows more hyperlinks and they close as they open so they are width and height of 0, just around title and content hyperlinks affects them and makes them linkable, to note again in code i have just one hyperlink.

*EDITED*

Somehow i have more links displayed even if i have one wrapped all the content, on browser it shows few more links and if i delete that one, they all removes

```
<li>
    <a class = "posts_link" href="www.google.com">
        <div class = "posts">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class = "posts_list">
                    <?php the_content('Read more...');?>
                    <div class = "clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class = "addition">
                    <div class = "add_time">
                        <time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> <?php the_time(); ?></time>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "add_comment">
                        <?php comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
        </div>
        </a>
</li>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all that you want to do is make the whole div clickable, there are certainly better ways. One of them would to add a onclick function to your div and write the function, could either be window.open or location.href, both will do the job.

Comment: yes i agree to you, but when is not necessary i dont want the users to suffer for not having javascript disabled.

Comment: In that case you can use a transparent mask image to overlay the area so that the a tag will have be given some height to cover the blog post area.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from this screen but did you add display:block to your a href? If you want an area to link you need to replace default display:inline to block..

Comment: yes, I tried that, but with display: block it just gives me width, the height is still 0...

Comment: Have you got any floats inside a href?

Comment: yes i do, but i cleared them and it seems like everything is okey with floats

Comment: hmmm what if you give a href a border? - just for a second - to see where it ends and if all divs sit inside..
Have you tried validating your code? Maybe there's missed closing tag somewhere..

Comment: I added the image of what i get if i add border.

Comment: Ok, for me it looks like missing closing tag - tried w3c validation? or php loops problem..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

1. You're using a foreach loop
2. The link is not being provided with any text

Untill the link is provided with text, its height and width will have no meaning at all. Because there is nothing you can click on. However adding a little bit padding might do the work.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/Jes6e/

```
a {
  padding: 5px; // to make it clickable
  border: 1px solid #333; // to make it visible..
}
```

In the fiddle you will see that the link is having no width or height but is still clickable. Why? Because it creates some space for the element to be clickable.

When there is no space, nothing is clickable and so no element is linked.

I have tested your code,

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/8NdnF/ Here is the fiddle for that. And guess what? Whole of the element is clickable.